# Selectable Table in JSP, JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a betting site using JSP and Servlets.

I need to create a selectable table of betting coefficients.
It looks like:

[image]

The scenario is:

User presses on the coefficients and makes a bet that can consist of different matches. I need to make the cells with coefficients selectable and allow only one selection in a row. Then i should get all the coefficients that were selected and put them into the request and do some stuff with them in my servlet.

Can I do this using JSP, Servlets and HTML ? Or I need some javascript code? 
I know almost nothing about javascript, so some links or small code listings would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you must do: 1. Set your table id as **table** 2.
On each row declare **onclick = 'choose(n);'**, where **n** the order of
rows beginning from 1; If you know JSP hope you know how make n
increment by each row;

**And pay Attention I am setting** *trLength* **by subtracting 1 from** *rows.length*, **only when there is header on table. So there must be header anyway, otherwise code won't work**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body onkeydown="chooseNext(event);">

    <table id="table">

        <th>name</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
        <th>score</th>
        <tr onclick="choose(1);">
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="choose(2);">
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="choose(3);">
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        /**
         *  
         *  
         * 
         * @author Abdullaev Omonullo, 2015
         */

        var IC = 1;

        function setRow(value) {
            IC = value;
        }

        function getRow() {
            return IC;
        }

    /**** Initialization ****/
    var rows = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var trLength = rows.length - 1;
    try {
        highlightAll();
    } catch (error) {
        alert('error on getting table: ' + error);
    }
    choose(getRow());
    function highlightAll() {
        var i = 1;
        for (; i <= trLength; i++) {
            highlightByIndex(i);
        }
    }

    /****END Initilization END****/

    function chooseNext(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            goUp();
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            goDown();
        }
    }

    function goUp() {
        if (IC != 1) {
            choose(IC - 1);
        }
    }

    function goDown() {
        if (IC != trLength) {
            choose(IC + 1);
        }
    }

    function highlight(rowIndex) {
        var row = rows[rowIndex];
        var oldRow = rows[rowIndex];

        highlightByIndex(parseInt(IC));

        row.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";

        IC = rowIndex;
    }

    function highlightByIndex(i) {
        var row = rows[i];

        var colors = [ '#C9EAFF', '#E8F6FF' ];
        row.style.backgroundColor = colors[i % 2];
    }

    function choose(rowIndex) {
        highlight(rowIndex);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry this was an old question, I did not pay attention

Answer (score 0):

you need to use javascript, try `datatables` it has the ability to do what you need.
http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html